# MongoDB Updating collection document with json object imported by client in meteor

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I have a JSON object that is imported by the client (imported as XLSX and converted to JSON).

Every JSON object has a reference and other several fields that get inserted in my collection.

What I'm trying to do is whenever a client imports a JSON object with a reference that is already in one of my collection documents I want to update that document with the updated fields and new ones imported by the client.

This is how I'm trying to reach it:

```
let keys = Object.keys(json.data[0]);
let values = Object.values(json.data[0]);
Adverts.update({'reference': json.data[0].reference}, {$set: {keys: values}}, {upsert: true});
```

I've checked the docs and other answers, seems like with upsert and $set is the way to go, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keys` and `values` are arrays, you can't do this:

... `{$set: {keys: values}}` ...

Instead try this:

```
Adverts.update({'reference': json.data[0].reference}, 
{$set: json.data[0] }, {upsert: true});
```

Comment: That answers my question. But even tho it updates my fields is also adds a duplicate of those. I'm using `Adverts._ensureIndex({"reference": 1}) `
do don't add duplciates, but still adds them...

Comment: provide a data sample before and after you executed the query. include the query as well. preferably in new SO question.Thanks !